# How to modify tags of an already existing svg object with data from json file

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this code snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1000" height="1000" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
         <path d="M377.4528 264.0669q3.7795-113.3858 151.1811-113.3858m0 0q0 11.3386 0 11.3386 0 139.8425-41.5748 139.8425m3.7795 0q-37.7953 0-37.7953 0 56.6929 0 56.6929 113.3858-132.2835 0-132.2835-79.3701"/>
         <path d="M377.4528 335.878q0 79.3701-132.2835 79.37-3.7795-113.3857 56.6929-113.3857-75.5905 0-75.5905-151.1812 151.1811 0 151.1811 113.3859"/>
         <ellipse cx="377.4528" cy="284.8543" rx="3mm" ry="16.5mm"/>
    </svg>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

         d3.json("./data.json").then(function(data){
             var svg = d3.select("body")
                         .selectAll("svg")
                         .... something here 
               })
    </script>
</body>
```

I cannot update, with values from data.json file, for example `cx`, `cy`, `rx` etc... and most of all values contained in `path` string. Someone can help me? Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example below I'm using a mock API to simulate your `d3.json()` request and then making up a new value for `rx` and `ry` for the ellipse. I've used timeout just for demonstration purposes so that you can see the ellipse changes - you wouldn't need to do that in your code.

So, once you have the new data, you can use a selection e.g. `d3.select("svg ellipse")` so you can then update the attributes of the selection.

If your new data has new `d` attributes for the `path` elements, then you can use the same  approach e.g. `path.attr("d", newD)`. If you want to change datapoints within the path definition, it would depend on your incoming data and better asked as a separate question.

```js
// mock api to make this snippet work
const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";

// wait for 1.5s and apply new attributes to ellipse
setTimeout(function() {
  // get the new data
  d3.json(url).then(function(data) {
    // mock up some data
    data = [{rx: "5mm", ry: "20mm"}];
    changeEllipse(data[0]);
  });
}, 1500);

function changeEllipse(data) {
  // select the ellipse with a selector
  const ellipse = d3.select("svg ellipse");
  // change attributes
  ellipse
    .attr("rx", data.rx)
    .attr("ry", data.ry);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1000" height="1000" stroke="#000" stroke- linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
  <path d="M377.4528 264.0669q3.7795-113.3858 151.1811-113.3858m0 0q0 11.3386 0 11.3386 0 139.8425-41.5748 139.8425m3.7795 0q-37.7953 0-37.7953 0 56.6929 0 56.6929 113.3858-132.2835 0-132.2835-79.3701"/>
  <path d="M377.4528 335.878q0 79.3701-132.2835 79.37-3.7795-113.3857 56.6929-113.3857-75.5905 0-75.5905-151.1812 151.1811 0 151.1811 113.3859"/>
  <ellipse cx="377.4528" cy="284.8543" rx="3mm" ry="16.5mm"/>
</svg>
```